# take a value from a dropdown and pass it to a variable

Tags: javascript, variables

I just got started with programming and I got stuck on this. I looked for the answer before posting but I am unable to sort out this code.

Basically I want to build a code that allows a user to select 2 values and then those values are passed on. It's a football/soccer predictor game if the actual score(var r and z) matches the predicted score(x and y) you should get 3 points, if only who wins is correct you get one. If you don't get the correct score but you get the number of goals difference between the two teams you get 2 points. here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var r = 3
var z = 1
var score = 0

var x = document.getElementById("resultHomeTeam").value;
var y = document.getElementById("resultAwayTeam").value;
var f = x-y
var j = r-z

function guru() {

    if(x==r && y==z) {

    score++}

    if(f == j){

    score++}

    if(r<z && x<y){
    score++}

    if(r>z && x>y){
    score++}

    if(r==z && x==y){
    score++

    }

    document.write("your score is " + score)
}



</script>

</head> 

<body>


Juventus
<select id = "resultHomeTeam">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
</select> 

Milan
 <select id = "resultAwayTeam">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
</select> 

<input type ="submit" value="submit" onclick =" return guru()"/>

<script type="text/javascript">



</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are doing it right, but see, On change of submit the guru() is getting called. But the values of the dropdown is selected on pageload. Rather x and y should be assigned inside guru(). Happy Coding!

Comment: Thank you very, very much :-)

Answer (score 0):

Declare the x and y inside the function `guru()`.And use with `parseInt()`

```js
var score = 0
  var r = 3
var z = 1


function guru() {

  var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("resultHomeTeam").value);
var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("resultAwayTeam").value);
var f = x - y
var j = r - z
  if (x == r && y == z) {
    score++
  }

  if (f == j) {
 console.log('2')
    score++
  }

  if (r < z && x < y) {
    score++
  }

  if (r > z && x > y) {
    score++
  }

  if (r == z && x == y) {
    score++

  }

  document.write("your score is " + score)
}
```

```html
Juventus
<select id="resultHomeTeam">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
</select>

Milan
<select id="resultAwayTeam">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick=" return guru()" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed! :)

Comment: Don't forget to mark as a answer.It helpful for future visitor's.happy coding...!